# default values for interfaces used with generic function

Tags: typescript, oop, typescript-generics

I'm building a type system around commands and command results. The ultimate goal is to construct commands and eventually serialize them to JSON over the network. There will be a lot of commands with different required fields. I was hoping to avoid creating many `sendCommandXXX()` functions, and instead use a generic function that can handle any command. What I have so far is:

```js
// base command structure required for all commands
interface CommandBase {
  name: string;
}

// example commands
interface CommandAddFile extends CommandBase {
  name: 'AddFile';
  filename: string;
  contents: string;
}

interface CommandDeleteFile extends CommandBase {
  name: 'DeleteFile';
  filename: string;
}

interface CommandRefreshResults extends CommandBase {
  name: 'RefreshResults'
}

// result structure
interface CommandResult {
  success: boolean;
  error?: string;
}

async sendCommand<T>(opts: T): Promise<CommandResult> {
  // ... send `opts` over network
}

sendCommand<CommandAddFile>({
  name: 'AddFile',
  filename: 'test.txt',
  contents: 'test'
}).then(res => {
  console.log(res.success);
});
```

Right now it feels repetitive to invoke sendCommand with both a specific command type in the template field, and specifying `name`, which would always want to be the same as a pair. How can I simplify this?

Comment: If you could get access to that generic type, you could build some logic to set the right name, but I don't think you can do that with TS.

Comment: @mwilson That was my thought as well, but as far as I can tell from TS docs you can't access that type outside the function signature.

Comment: Yea, given that that's the only to determine which type of comand to run (and thus adding the right `name`), it's probably not possible to do anything "automagical" with your current setup. I think I have an idea on a different way to approach it. I'll throw it in as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

What about changing it around and attacking it the other way? Instead of having a lot of different interfaces and inheritance, you could just create a class that has the logic around each command. All of the commands then call a base command that has the generic setup.

Here's something that I think might be a little cleaner and consolidated:

```
/**
 * Command Names
 */
enum Commands {
    AddFile = 'AddFile'
}

/**
 * Add File
 */
interface CommandAddFile {
    filename: string;
}

/**
 * Cli class with static methods
 */
class MyCli {
    /**
     * Base command execution
     * @param opts
     */
    private static executeCommand<T>(commandName: string, opts: T): T {
        // ...
        return {} as T;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a file
     * @param opts
     * @constructor
     */
    static AddFile(opts: CommandAddFile): Promise<CommandAddFile> {
        const result = this.executeCommand<CommandAddFile>(Commands.AddFile, opts);
        return Promise.resolve(result);
    }
}

// Usage
MyCli.AddFile({} as CommandAddFile).then( res => console.log(res) );
```

You could then just drop the `name` prop all together and either pass it in as a param to `MyCli.executeCommand` or set the property before it gets passed.

Comment: Thank you for putting together this example. Using enums gives me a few additional ideas. One pain point still is the amount of times "AddFile" appears in the code. I'm hoping for something that simplifies the boilerplate while also allowing for type adherence (this may not be possible)